# Why does my BitArray split?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
bittrans = '0b' + str(bitnumber)
strnumber = bitstring.BitArray(bittrans)
print bittrans
print strnumber
```

Which outputs:

```
0b1001010100000010111110001111111111
0x9502f8ff, 0b11
```

How do I stop the bitstring form splitting itself?

Comment: I think that the size is to big but later on in the code I can append other bitstrings to it without a problem

Comment: `bittrans` is a string, but `strnumber` is a `BitArray` object. `print`ing a string obviously prints out the string, but `print`ing an object means that the object needs to convert itself into a string first. In this case, [`BitArray` tries to do some fancy stuff](https://github.com/scott-griffiths/bitstring/blob/master/bitstring.py#L931-L956).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the string representation that `BitArray` uses to make your bitarray simpler to look at if you `print` it out. It has nothing to do with the internal representation.

It splits because `BitArray.__str__` wants to represent your bitarray as a bunch of bytes, like so:

```
0x95 02 f8 ff ?
```

You can't represent your bitstring as bytes unambiguously because the number of bits in your bitstring isn't a multiple of 8:

```
In [60]: len('1001010100000010111110001111111111') % 8
Out[60]: 2
```

Notice that's how many bits are left over in the string representation you have in your question. You will have to pad your number with 6 more bits to make it representable as a "single" hex number.

You can instead print out `strnumber.bin`:

```
In [75]: print strnumber.bin
1001010100000010111110001111111111
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation but if I want to append strnumber.bin to a Bitarray it throws a ValueError: Token has no value

Comment: @OberonMeier: I'm not sure you understood what I was trying to say. Calling `print strnumber` and `strnumber.bin` just make text representations of `strnumber`. You shouldn't have to convert `strnumber` to a string to work with it, that defeats the whole point of having a `BitArray` object. You can just do `bitarray_object_a.append(bitarray_object_b)`